# Redirect aws lb endpoint to non-ec2 infrastructure

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a browser plugin, which calls a backend service currently running on AWS Ec2/ Load balancer. My plugin calls a load balancer endpoint to talk to the service running on my ec2. I am now planning to move away from EC2 and start using my own infrastructure. I don't want to break existing installation of browser plugins. Essentially, i want is to redirect the calls made to load balancer end point to my infrastructure. How do i go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't use Elastic Load Balancers (ELB) to redirect to anything other than an EC2 instance.

You have a couple of options:

**Best Option:** If your browser plugin calls a hostname like plugin.mydomain.com, then just update the DNS to point to your new stuff.  This amounts to switching your A record to point to the new endpoint.  If, however, your browser plugin has hardcoded the Elastic Load Balancer endpoint, then let's look at...

**Next Option:** Keep your ELB in place, but put 1 or 2 t2-family instances behind it.  Then configure the t2 instance to redirect traffic to your new server.

You can even return an HTTP 301 Permanent URL Redirect response (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) to signal to the browser plugins that going forward they should query this new endpoint.  Sometimes browsers cache that response and will respect the permanent redirect going forward.

Comment: Thanks Josh. option 1, would work only if i had a custom domain name, right? i have the default dns name for my load balancer. so i guess #2 is only option.

Comment: Yeah, if you hardcoded the ELB's endpoint name, then the only way to change that is hardcode it to something else. That's why it's a good idea to use generic hostnames, so you can update where the hostname points without updating the hostname itself.  So, yeah, only option is to take the setup you've got and tell your servers to redirect.

Comment: Can you either accept my response, or indicate why you need more info to close the thread?

Answer (score 0):

From https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/:

> You can load balance any application hosted in AWS or on-premises using IP addresses of the application backends as targets.